# Order element of a quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a finite group, $H$ a normal soubgrup of $G$ and $|G/H|=n$. Let a $\in G$. If  $|a| = m$ then $|aH|=(m,n)$.

Because of $a^{n}H = H$ and $a^{m}H = H$, then $|aH||(m,n)$.  Suppose that $|aH| < (m,n)$:

$a^{(m,n)-|aH|}H = H$

This means that $2(m,n) = |aH|$ or $(m,n)=|aH|$.

---

Is this razoning right?. If so, how can I end this proof?

Comment: lol.. Yes, they are. :c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. Let $G= \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, and let $H$ be the second factor. Then $|G/H|=2$. Let $a=(0,1) \in H$. Then $|a|=2$ so $(|a|,|G/H|)=2$, but $|aH|=1$ since $a \in H$.

Answer (score 0):

This is unclear and wrong.  If $aH$ indicates a coset, it has the same size as $H$.  If $aH$ indicates the subgroup generated by $a$ and $H$, which should be denoted $<a,H>$, the group of the square gives a counterexample.  Let $H$ be the 4 rotations and $a$ be any reflection.  The. $H$ has order 4, $a$ order 2, but they generate the entire group, which has order 8.

The formula you want is that the size of the set of pairwise products of two subgroups (which is it itself a subgroup of either of them is normal) is the product of the sizes divided by the size of the intersection.

Comment: I think the OP intended $|aH|$ to mean the order of the element $aH$ (i.e. the order of the subgroup it generates) in the group $G/H$, not the cardinality of the coset. Agree that the notation is poor.

Comment: Ah, $o(aH)$.  Still doesn't work since if $o(a)$ and $|H|$ are coprime then $o(aH)$ is equal to $o(a)$, not to $1$.